# create a list error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I created a new custom list , I added columns (17 columns), I went back to The all items page , it show this error

> **TypeError: unable to get property 0 of undefined or null reference**

PS- The list is empty

Comment: Maybe have to install a cumulative update.

Comment: Were any of the columns lookup type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to trace your issue by doing the following:**

- Create a new view from existing view that has the issue.

[image]

- In your case start from all items view.

[image]

- Start removing the columns one by one from the latest added to the oldest.
- Every time you remove a column, try to check if your view is rendered properly or not.
- In case the view is rendered properly so the last column you have removed is the column that causes the issue.
- Now try to check if you face the same issue with a new list or not? if it's a general issue for all lists so try to [find the latest CU installed in your farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/) and install a new CU.

  - It's recommended to install the latest CU - 1)
  - Note all new CU requires SharePoint 2013 SP1 installed.
- If the issue still not solved after applying the new CU, So try to contact Microsoft.

Comment: Your guidelines helped me , remove task outcome column solve the issue , I want to know why the task outcome cause fault render

Comment: what's your current CU installed in your farm/

Comment: Service pack 1!!

Comment: I have SP 2016 and I can add this type of column, Do you able to install a new CU? if yes go ahead to install the latest CU (current month -1) otherwise use the choice field instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

Go to **Modify view** in ribbon then Change field "**Item Text (linked to item with edit menu)**" to "**Item Text (linked to item)**".

Comment: It's not worked!