# Task list error - Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

I am getting a strange error on Task list view

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null
>   referenceTypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or
>   null reference  TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of
>   undefined or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property 'length'
>   of undefined or null referenceTypeError: Unable to get property
>   '_events' of undefined or null reference

Has anyone faced this error and know the solution?

Comment: What's the current CU? do you try to add a new column like Outcome Task to the default Task view, When exactly you got this error? check also this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225384/create-a-list-error

Comment: Thanks @M.Qassas, it was the "Type" field that i removed and the issue got fixed. The issue was on the "All Items" view.

Comment: Good job, @Ahmed, and thanks for your feedback at the below answer,  Please don't forget also to upvote it as helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens normally with a field in that list.
Try removing the field from the view one by one to find the problematic field.

Try first removing the `"Type (icon linked to document)"` field as most of the time this error is due to that.

Comment: Thanks @Saira. It got fixed by removing the "Type" field from the view.